# RecordTypeName without using SOQL

Tags: apex

I'm using a custom object. Its instantiated on the controller as

```
this.stdController = controller; 
this.AccountSummary = (Account_Summary__c) controller.getRecord();
```

I'm using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType')` which returns the ID of the recordtype.

I see how to get the record type name using the standard SalesForce OOTB Account object.

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().getR‌​ecordTypeInfosById()‌​.get(strRecordTypeId‌​).getName();
```

How do I get a handle to this custom object using getGlobalDescribe ?

Updated:

```
this.RecordTypeId =   
      ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType'); 
String RecordTypeName =         
      Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
          .get('Account_Summary__c')
          .getDescribe()
          .getR‌​ecordTypeInfosById()‌​
          .get(RecordTypeId‌​)
          .getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

You get it in the exact same manner:

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account_Summary__c').getDescribe().getR‌​ecordTypeInfosById()‌​.get(strRecordTypeId‌​).getName();
```

Note that getGlobalDescribe is computationally expensive, and should be avoided. If the type of object is known in advance, you should specify it directly:

```
Account_Summary__c.getDescribe().getR‌​ecordTypeInfosById()‌​.get(strRecordTypeId‌​).getName();
```

Even if you don't know the type, you can still save some CPU time by asking the record what type of object it is:

```
String recordTypeName = AccountSummary.getSObjectType().getDescribe()
    .getRecordTypeInfosById().get(strRecordTypeId).getName();
```

Comment: Getting Error: AccountSummaryController Compile Error: line 253:129 no viable alternative at character '‌' at line 253 using the updated code above:

Comment: @rickmac You have some zero-width spaces in your code. Try typing it in manually.